# Why is my data not being passed from storyboard to xib file in Xcode objective c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode7

I have created a storyboard(ViewController) and a xib file(TargetVC) . My views are fine . But data is not getting passed from one View controller to target view controller . here is my code

**Viewcontroller.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "TargetVC.h"

@interface ViewController : UIViewController
{
    TargetVC   *target ;
}

@property (retain , nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *InputData;
- (IBAction)SendData:(id)sender;

@end
```

**viewcontroller.m**

```
#import "ViewController.h"

    @interface ViewController ()
    @end

@implementation ViewController

@synthesize InputData ;

- (IBAction)SendData:(id)sender {

    target = [[TargetVC alloc]initWithNibName:@"TargetVC" bundle:nil];
    target.userText = InputData ;
    [self.view addSubview:target.view];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

@end
```

**TargetVC.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface TargetVC : UIViewController
{
    UITextField *userText;
}

@property (retain , nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *ResultLabel;
@property (retain , nonatomic)UITextField *userText;

@end
```

**TargetVC.m**

```
#import "TargetVC.h"

@interface TargetVC ()

@end

@implementation TargetVC

@synthesize ResultLabel , userText;

- (void)viewDidLoad {

    userText.text = ResultLabel.text ;
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code the `ViewController` creates the `TargetVC` and then sets the `userText` value of the `TargetVC`.  You then reset the `userText.txt` value to the value of `ResultLabel.text` however you don't show where `ResultLabel.text` had its value set.

You can change this

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    userText.text = ResultLabel.text ;
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

to this

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
   [super viewDidLoad];
   ResultLabel.text = userText.text;
}
```

if you are trying to set the value of the `ResultLabel.text`

or if you are trying to set the value `UITextField` of the `ViewController` class then you should set `ViewController` as a delegate of `TargetVC` and pass the data that way.

If you are trying to do something else then please update your question with clarification and I will update/delete my response.

Comment: Thanks dude . Finally the mistake has been found . In TargetVC.h i have declared a NSString object as UITextField object . So the data could,t be passed . Now it rectified . Thank you .